# How to redirect specific calls to other ip?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain, and some static content. I would like all of the static content to be served from my domain. However, I would like all requests with `**/api/**` - for example: `http://mydomain/api/users`) to be forwarded to my other server, with IP address of for example `10.1.10.100` (irrelevant at this time).

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use proxypass.

Comment: @123, could you provide any example?

Comment: You need to have server side control of `mydomain` for using proxy